# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor

Tags: beamer, color

I have an option clash between package `xcolor` and another package, but I don't know which. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}

\author{The author}
\title{Package conflicts}
\date{October 3rd, 2012}

\begin{document}

This is supposed to be \textcolor{olivegreen}{olivegreen}
\end{document}
```

And the error message is :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./error_xcolor.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
<blablabla>
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
```

I hope this is enough `log` for you guys. At this time of the day, I'm hoping for America to save my french ass ... again : )

Comment: I think the duplicate is wrong. The pointed-to question is for clashes created by `usepackage`, this is for clashes created by `documentclass`, that can't be resolved by reorganizing the order of loading.

Comment: Or at least, this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567959/where-how-and-when-to-load-xcolor-options is a better duplicate.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) class loads `xcolor` per default. You can issue the option via a `beamer`-option

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={usenames}]{beamer}
```

`olivegreen` on the other hand needs the `dvipsnames` option *and* is called `OliveGreen`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}

\author{The author}
\title{Package conflicts}
\date{October 3rd, 2012}

\begin{document}

This is supposed to be \textcolor{OliveGreen}{olivegreen}
\end{document}
```

---

You could do

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames}]{beamer}
```

but don't (`usenames` is obsolete).
TeXLive 2009 is old …

Comment: I faced the same issue with the `article` class and this didn't worked for me (TeX Live 2019). I had to use the folowwing macro : `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}`

Comment: You can just do `\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}` which will forward `dvipsnames` to *all* packages – if they support such an option.

Answer (score 32):

that is a problem with beamer which should pass the package option not in this way. You can use

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
[...]
```

The same problem occurs if you want to load options for package `graphicx`. Then you also have to use the macro `\PassOptionsToPackage`

Comment: This one worked for me but I am not using beamer, I am using a custom .cls from my organization.   This solution may be a solution for those who are not looking at beamer specifically.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=tex,dvipsnames,table,10pt]{beamer}
```

Comment: We need more detail here. Can you provide the motivation behind this answer?