# Fancy slides latex

Tags: color, presentations

I am using [fancy slides](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/presentations) for a presentation.

The problem is that I want to be able to specify some colors with xcolor. When I try to do the usual

```
  \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
```

I get an error:

```
    ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package color.
```

Did anyway encounter this before?

Thank you!

Edit: I am using the `fancyslides` class.

Comment: The error message means, that you or some other package loaded before has already loaded `color` (or `xcolor`) with different options, which exclude each other mutually.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I do not use the beamer class but 
`\documentclass{fancyslides}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  I understand that, but I did not do it manually, I guess it is the class that I use that does it before me. I wonder if someone got this before.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, @elaRosca: `fancyslides` seems to use beamer effectively

Comment: My code is this '\documentclass{fancyslides}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}' so I the clash does not come from me but from the package

Comment: I just checked it: `fancyslides` uses `\LoadClass{beamer}` and therefore `xcolor` is already loaded

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are right, I get the same error message if I replace fancy slides with the beamer class. I just want to be able to name colours like 'OliveGreen' and so on

Comment: Try `\documentclass[x11names]{fancyslides}` or `\documentclass[dvipsnames]{fancyslides}`

Comment: Is it a possible duplicate of [LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74805/13304)?