# How to Get Vertical Timeline work in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I am trying to reproduce the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196808/13173) about *How can you create a vertical timeline?* in Beamer (not OS X specific only). 
I installed TeX By MacTeX. 
I have these packages in OSX `xcolor`, `colortbl` and `caption` because Test code 1 works and verified also by *Tex Live Utility*.

### Test code 1

Works:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\caption{Timeline}\vskip -1.5ex
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
\toprule
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
1933 & LCMV, aseptic meningitis. Epidemic St. Loius encephalitis. \\
1956 & Tacaribe virus.  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

### Test code 2

Does not work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

- - same as above - -
```

Output

```
Latex Error: ./test_timeline.tex:11 LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.

Latex Error: ./test_timeline.tex:45 Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `LightSteelBlue3'.

Latex Error: ./test_timeline.tex:46 Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `LightSteelBlue3'.

...
```

---

How can you get a vertical timeline in Beamer?

Comment: none of the packages you mention is operating system dependent, why do you think OS X is involved?

Comment: `sudo tlmgr install xcolor colortbl caption`?

Comment: maybe you need to update file name data base and formats?

Comment: How did you install TeX exactly? Did you use MacTeX?

Comment: In that case, you should already have all of those packages installed. They are all installed by MacTeX. Why do you think HomeBrew is involved? If you can create a Minimal Non-Working Example and post the code for that example, that would be helpful. You can then post the `.log` file you get from trying to compile that example somewhere. (It may not fit here.)

Comment: @cfr I managed to get problem forward. The thing is that the code does not work in Beamer but works elsewhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "problem" is, that beamer already loads xcolor and your `[x11names]` causes an option clash. Fortunately `beamer` has an own build-in option.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,table]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}
\caption{Timeline}\vskip -1.5ex
\begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
\toprule
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
1933 & LCMV, aseptic meningitis. Epidemic St. Loius encephalitis. \\
1956 & Tacaribe virus.  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am extending this thread to involve cuts in the timeline here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303039/13173 Do you have any ideas about how to get one?

Comment: How to revert to black border to other tables after this ? Getting blue borders for tables after this

Comment: @tex Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 3):

This answer uses `\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names}{xcolor}` following @Herbert's answer ([LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74805/latex-error-option-clash-for-package-xcolor)). The caption is in a `minipage` environment to align it with the vertical timeline.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{x11names}{xcolor}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{LightSteelBlue3}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=blue, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad}

\begin{minipage}{7cm}
    \caption{Timeline}
\end{minipage}
\vskip -1.5ex

\begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 2pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
\toprule
\addlinespace[1.5ex]
1933 & LCMV, aseptic meningitis. Epidemic St. Loius encephalitis. \\
1956 & Tacaribe virus.  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]