# How to get this package in TexLive 2016 of Debian?

Tags: packages, debian, texlive-2016

Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,table]{beamer} 
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303091/13173
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196808/13173
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303021/13173

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
   \color{LightSteelBlue3}%
   \makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}%
   \hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt%
   \hspace{\labelsep}%
}

\newlength{\CVbreakdotsep}% length to change spacing between dots
\setlength{\CVbreakdotsep}{0.1mm}

\newcommand{\CVbreakdot}{% command for smaller dots
   \scalebox{0.4}{\textbullet}%
}

\newcommand{\CVbreak}{% command for the break itself
   \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
      \hspace*{8.7mm}% <--- align dots with vertical line
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{%
         \color{LightSteelBlue3}%
         \hspace{-5.3mm}% <--- extra vertical space
         \CVbreakdot\kern\CVbreakdotsep\CVbreakdot
      }%
   } \\[-3.6mm]%
}

\begin{document} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Timeline}

\begin{table}
   \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
   \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} % Label ``Table'' is not suppressed
   \caption{Timeline as map $\mathbf K \times \mathbf K$ with a linear trend 1 sp / 3 years, really?}\vskip -1.5ex
   \arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
   \begin{tabular}{@{\,}r <{\hskip 1.3pt} !{\foo} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{8cm}}
      \toprule
      \addlinespace[1.0ex]
1933 & LCMV, aseptic meningitis. Epidemic St. Loius encephalitis. \\
1956 & Tacaribe virus. \\
1958 & Junin virus (ArHF), Argentina. \\
{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output

- Errors and warnings in compiling with XeLaTeX in Texlive 2014 and 2016

  ```
  ! LaTeX Error: File `heuristica.sty' not found.
  ```
- Output as .pdf in TexLive 2014 and 2016

  [image]

### My work flow in debugging

```
masi@masi:~/$ apt-cache search heuristica
libtext-findindent-perl - module to heuristically determine indentation style
texlive-fonts-extra - TeX Live: Additional fonts
libssw0 - fast SIMD parallelized implementation of the Smith-Waterman algorithm

masi@masi:~/$ su
root@masi:~/# apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-fonts-extra is already the newest version.
texlive-fonts-extra set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@masi:~/# apt-get install libtext-findindent-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtext-findindent-perl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 14.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 81.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libtext-findindent-perl all 0.10-1 [14.1 kB]
Fetched 14.1 kB in 0s (53.3 kB/s)                  
Selecting previously unselected package libtext-findindent-perl.
(Reading database ... 315958 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libtext-findindent-perl_0.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtext-findindent-perl (0.10-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up libtext-findindent-perl (0.10-1) ...

# running now xelatex test.tex gives the same output
```

### My workflow about in TexLive 2016

- I do as root for the installation of the texlive 2016

  ```
  apt-get purge texlive-full

  # http://latex-community.org/know-how/466-texlive-linux
  cd Desktop
  mkdir texlive
  cd texlive
  wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
  tar xf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
  cd install-tl-20130105 (or a newer version)
  ./install-tl
  ```
- I add the following into my `$HOME/.bashrc` for the completion of the installation

  ```
  #Add /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/info to INFOPATH.
  # Add /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/man to MANPATH
  #   (if not dynamically found).
  # 
  # Most importantly, add /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux
  # to your PATH for current and future sessions.

  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux    
  export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/info
  export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/doc/man
  ```
- I run the .tex code again with XeLaTeX but get still the message again about *heuristica*. So the same problem persists in TexLive 2016.

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 (backports)
TexLive: `texlive-full` 2016

Comment: Update you TeX Live. B.t.w., `erewhon` , based on `Heuristica`,  has more glyphs.

Comment: also the first warning from inputenc is because you are using xetex. As the warning says, you should not use inputenc with xetex.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a Debian user. Don't you have TeX Live package manager (`tlmgr`)? Perhaps you should update to TeX Live 2016.

Comment: TeX Live 2014 is quite old; `heuristica` was added to TeX Live on 2015/01/05, so it doesn't belong to TeX Live/Debian that, as far as I remember, was not being kept updated. Its location on TL is `collection-fontextra`, so if that Debian package hasn't it, the only way out is updating TeX Live.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: You have to put the new TeX binaries at the beginning: `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

1. Correct `$HOME/.bashrc`

   ```
   % egrep
   export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
   ```
2. Include the package

   ```
   \usepackage{caption}
   ```
3. Output is expected one

   [image]