# How to Get latest Lyx in Latest LaTeX installation of Debian?

Tags: lyx, installing, debian

I can install the latest LaTeX in my Debian 8.5 as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329504/13173) at the end of the question body. 
Apt-get does not have the latest Lyx (2.1.2 < 2.2.1), but I would like to have it and control it centrally with my LaTeX installation. 
I could not find anything about it with the tool *install-tl*.

OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, write (and join?) to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org. There are Debian users there using the latest LyX.

Comment: Currently sid has 2.2.0. If that is good enough you can use [pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i dont think the *install-tl* tool can control the update of LyX. Lyx are independent of TeXLive (i suppose you use TeXLive).

But look at this link : https://www.guyrutenberg.com/debian/jessie/
You can find LyX v.2.2.1 for Debian Jessie.

I have not test it because i run on a FreeBSD box.

I hope this will help you!