# where, how, and when to load xcolor options

Tags: beamer, color

Here I load xcolor options (dvipsnames) at the very top, so all the xcolor friends don't have to sweat it, but options are like politics at Thanksgiving: s*** hits the fan no matter what:

```
\documentclass[10pt,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
```

Apologies, I tried to select the text in overleaf but when I let go of the mouse the selection disappears (it's that been kind of day):

[image]

Comment: `beamer` load `xcolor`, so you nod need to load it again and had not to load it with different options as you declare in document class. So, in your case just remove second line (with `xcolor`) in the code: `\documentclass[10pt,usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer} 
\usepackage{pgfpages}`

Comment: If you don't want to specify global options (that's what options to the `\documentclass` are), you can also use `\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}` *before* `xcolor` gets loaded (so before `\documentclass` in this case). Please note that the `usenames` option is obsolete according to `xcolor`'s documentation.

Comment: do you need any options? xcolor is already loaded, you can't load it again?

Comment: Thanks all for the extremely helpful replies.  In hindsight, it should have been obvious to me from lines 1-2 both having [dvipsnames...] that xcolor was being loaded by beamer. @Zarko if you want to place your comment in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It's moments like these that help me [slowly] transition from pasting fragments of code found on the internet to writing latex "with intention", haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document class `beamer` load (among others also) package `xcolor`, so you not need to load it again. If you do, as you show in your question, you get clash between `xcolor` options. So, in your case just remove second line (with `xcolor`) in the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,dvipsnames]{beamer}  
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[font=\Huge, text=Cyan] {Hello!};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Please note, that the `usenames` option is obsolete according to documentation of the `xcolor`, so I omit this option in above MWE.

As stated in the @Skillmon comment:  "If you don't want to specify global options (that's what options to the \verb+\documentclass+ are), you can also use
`\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames}{xcolor}`
before `xcolor` gets loaded, i.e.:"

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor} % now option(s) doesn't clash,
                    % however you not need to load it again! 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[font=\Huge, text=Cyan] {Hello!};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In both cases, the result is the same:

[image]

Comment: super clear explanation. Fi ally I get I :)

Answer (score 3):

On page 20 of the manual for `beamer`, you find

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames},
]{beamer}
```

I recommend this way of typing long list of options to classes, so one has all of them in view and commenting/uncommenting them is easier.