# \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}?

Tags: errors, color, dvips

I want to use the colours offered by

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

in a beamer but I have an error:

```
Option clash for package xcolor. \usepackage
```

I am using the following packages:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parallel,enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{ dsfont }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{multicol}
```

Comment: Beamer already loads xcolor. There is a special beamer class option to pass on options for xcolor, you'll need to look it up in the beamer manual.

Comment: @daleif I have tried the full MWE:`\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parallel,enumitem}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
A generic test
\end{document}` and it works correctly.

Comment: Try `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}`  *before* the `\documentclass`... (Not sure if it'll work)

Comment: @Sebastino the op might be on an older version of beamer.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74805/latex-error-option-clash-for-package-xcolor/74807#74807 it is marked as a duplicate, but the answers are better there than in the duplicate IMHO

Comment: @Sebastiano because there is not \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

Comment: @daleif I have not seen your comment because my name is written not correctly :-(

Comment: @MementoMori Because I have forgotten to put in a minimal working example. Excuse me. You use the comment of Rmano using: \PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}.

Comment: I have solved using the first answer to the question linked by @Rmano

Comment: Thank you all !!!!