# How to use xcolor color names in tikzpicture style?

Tags: color, tikz-styles, tikz-pic

I want to use color names like `MidnightBlue` in a style for a `tikzpicture` to e.g. fill it with a specific color, is this possible? Or am I limited to the other style (`red!30` etc.)?

This MWE fails with `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color MidnightBlue.`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[myStyle/.style={rectangle, fill=MidnightBlue}]
    \node (test) [myStyle] { Test };         
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package `tikz` (by way of package `pgfcore`) loads the `xcolor` package.

In your case, the `standalone` class with the option `tikz` *also* loads the `tikz` package (and configurates other settings so that it works as intended).
The `\usepackage{tikz}` has no effect anymore.

Thus, you need to say

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
```

or even just

```
\documentclass[svgnames,tikz]{standalone}
```

in your preamble.

Without `standalone` you can just do

```
\documentclass{article}% or another that does not load TikZ
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

or, similarly as with `standalone`,

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

---

Similar problems arise with the `beamer` class, however this one has [a class option `xcolor`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74807/16595) that can be used to forward options only to the `xcolor` package (`xcolor=dvipsnames`) – and not to all packages.