# Drawing graph: using (x,y) coordinate rather than angle to determine the position of the vertices

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

In the following answer to draw a graph, is there a way to use (x,y) coordinate rather than angle to determine the position of the vertices to draw the same graph?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653829/148579

What I expect is to draw a graph similar to the following image:

[image]

Edite: Compilation errors:

I use the following `document class` and the compile is done by Overleaf.
The screenshot shows the received errors after compilation:

[image]

As you can see the `begin document` is inserted after:

[image]

Comment: You can convert from polar to rectangular coordinates, but what would the advantage be?

Comment: @Sandy G , Assume we want to put a vertex close to (and not exactly) the center of the Hexagon, how to do it?

Comment: @Sandy G , I edited the question by adding an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [answer by Sandy G](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653865/16595) already answers your initial question but I want to give another way to draw ths picture with TikZ. The key `decide color` might be usable with that other answer, too, since you won't need to specify the color implicitly in the list.

With the support of LuaLaTeX we can use TikZ' `graphdrawing` and its `force` library.

The [`force` library](https://tikz.dev/gd-force) (`\usegdlibrary{force}`) provides the [`spring electrical layout`](https://tikz.dev/gd-force#pgf.spring:electrical:layout).

The [`graphs` library](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs) (`\usetikzlibrary{graphs}`) provides the [`typeset` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#pgf./tikz/graphs/typeset) that is used to define the node text dependent on the node's name.

This name will also be used in `decide color` to apply the appropriate color style:

```
decide color/.style 2 args={
  /utils/TeX if=c#1
    {% if the first letter is c
     % and the number after is is smaller than 5 → bluelight
     %                                 otherwise → bluedark
      /utils/if={#2<5}{bluelight}{bluedark}
    }{% if the first letter is not c (i.e. p)
      % and the number after it is smaller than 8 → light
      %                                 otherwuse → dark
      /utils/if={#2<8}{light}{dark}
    }
}
```

### Code

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /utils/if/.code n args={3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\relax
    \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\fi
    {\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}},
  /utils/TeX if/.code n args={4}{%
    \if#1#2\expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\fi
    {\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  mynode/.style={
    circle, minimum size=10mm, draw, densely dashdotted, thick,
    decide color/.expand once=#1},
  decide color/.style 2 args={
    /utils/TeX if=c#1% c1-c4 / c5- / ?1-?7 / ?8-
      {/utils/if={#2<5}{bluelight}{bluedark}}
      {/utils/if={#2<8}{light}{dark}}},
  light/.style={fill=gray!20},  bluelight/.style={fill=blue!10},
  dark/.style ={fill=gray!60},  bluedark/.style ={fill=blue!30}}
\begin{document}
\tikz\graph[
  spring electrical layout, horizontal=c2 to p13,
  node distance=1.5cm, typeset=$n_{\tikzgraphnodetext}$,
  nodes={mynode=\tikzgraphnodetext}] {
  % outer ring
  c2 -- {p1, p11, p6};
    p1 -- {p8, c6, p11};
      p8 -- {p3, p10, c6};
       p3 -- {p13, p15, p10};
         p13 -- {p15, c7};
           c7  -- {c3, c4, p15};
           c3  -- {p14, c4};
           p14 -- {p7, c4};
         p7 -- {p9, p2, c4};
       p9 -- {c5, p12, p2};
     c5 -- {c1, p4, p12};
   c1 -- {p6, p4};
  p6 -- {p11, p4};
  % inner ring
  p11 -- {c6, p12, p4};
  p5 -- {c6 -- {p10, p12}, p10 -- p15, p15 -- c4, c4 -- p2, p2 -- p12, p12 -- p4};
  % last line is equivalent to:
  % c6 -- {p10, p5, p12}; p10 -- {p15, p5}; p15 -- {c4, p5};
  % c4 -- {p2, p5};       p2  -- {p12, p5}; p12 -- {p4, p5};
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Since I received errors after compilation, I added related screenshots to the question.

Comment: And how to use `LuaLaTeX` ? (I am using `Overleaf` online compiler)

Comment: Done, but i don't know what's the conflict with `algorithm2e`, because I get now this error: `\usepackage [ruled]{algorithm2e} The package xcolor has already been loaded with options: [] There has now been an attempt to load it with options [dvipsnames] Adding the global options: ,dvipsnames to your \documentclass declaration may fix this. Try typing  <return>  to proceed.`

Comment: @Questioner That's the same problem as [recently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/653721). Has nothing to do with this answer. Easiest would be to move `\usepackage[rules]{algorithm2e}` before `\usepackage{tikz}`.

Comment: @Questioner , I tried to make the vertices a bit smaller but then there is no space for the labels. Is there a solution to do it? By changing the font or any other method.

Comment: @Questioner The nodes are usually at least as big as their content. Remove or adjust `minimum size` and also try to play with the `inner sep` setting (defaults to `.3333em`). You can also set `text width`, `text depth` and `text height` to force the content to be a special size with the text protruding these dimensions if it's bigger.

Comment: I think a ggod solution is to convert `n_{p1}` to `p_{1}` etc. and doing the same think for `n` , that is, `n_{c1}` to `c_{1}` etc. but I do now how to replace `n` with `p` and `c`.

Comment: @Questioner Remove `typeset=$n_{\tikzgraphnodetext}$` from the `\graph` command's options and add `graphs/typeset={$#1_{#2}$}` to `decide color`.

Comment: Could you say exactly when in `decide color` ? after `expand` ? after `style` ? inside `args` ? or ... I receive error.

Comment: Beside error message, there is no `n` and `p` so that all of vertices are labeld `1_{2}`

Comment: @Questioner `decide color/.style 2 args={graphs/typeset={$#1_{#2}$}, /utils/TeX if=…}` should work.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started. Make two for loops: the first to name and draw the nodes, the second to draw the edges. Each entry in the node list should have the form `<x>/<y>/<fillcolor>/<label>/<name>`. For the edge list, use the names from the first for loop.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={circle, minimum size=12mm, draw, densely dashdotted}}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{color1}{gray!20}
\colorlet{color2}{gray!60}
\colorlet{color3}{blue!20}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x/\y/\col/\lab/\nam in 
    {0/0/color1/n_{p1}/p1, -1/3/color2/n_{p2}/p2, 1/5/color1/n_{p5}/p5, 4/4/color2/n_{c5}/c5, 5/1/color3/n_{c1}/c1, 3/0/color3/n_{p11}/p11, 2/2/color1/n_{c2}/c2}
    {\node[mynode, fill=\col] (\nam) at (\x,\y){$\lab$};}
\foreach \p/\q in {p5/c5, c5/c1, c1/p11, p11/p1, p1/p2, p2/p5, c2/c5, c2/p11, c2/c1, c2/p1, c2/p2, c2/p5}
    {\draw (\p)--(\q);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: PGFfor allows the first variable in the list to be a coordinate (even if there's a `,` in it): `\foreach \pos/\col/\lab/\nam in {(0,0)/color1/n_{p1}/p1, …, (2,2)/color1/n_{c2}/c2} \node[mynode, fill=\col] (\nam) at \pos {$\lab$};` which might be a more natural way to specify the coordinates. And it allows `(60:2)` or even `([xshift=5pt]0,0)` without relying solely on `\x` and `\y` coordinates.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: That's a good point. I will let OP decide which to use.